# stock [uncountable] vs livestock [uncountable, plural]

Tags: grammatical-number, uncountable-nouns

> [STOCK](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/stock_1?q=stock) [**uncountable**]: farm animals, such as cows and sheep,
> that are kept for their meat, wool, etc. SEE ALSO *livestock*
>
> [LIVESTOCK](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/stock_1?q=stock) [**uncountable, plural**]: animals kept on a farm, for
> example cows or sheep [https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/stock_1?q=stock)

The difference between both terms is the possibility of being a plural noun that only livestock offers.
Is this correct?

Comment: That seems weird, but did you check other dictionaries? A dictionary may not be perfectly consistent within itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Merriam-Webster Learner's Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/livestock) gives the two examples for **livestock**:

> - *a market where livestock are bought and sold*
> - *a market where livestock is bought and sold*

However, it does not assign countness / non-countness here in accordance with how CGEL regards it. Since neither sentence accepts a numeral or equivalent

> *a market where three livestock/s are bought and sold
>
> *a market where a dozen livestock/s is bought and sold

the usages must **both** be deemed **non-count**.

The correct way to describe these usages is '**used with either a singular or a plural verb-form**'.

Also, comparing with the unacceptable notional plural form 'livestocks', 'livestock' is **of singular form** (no -*s*).

Note also that 'livestock' refers to an *etically countable referent*, perhaps 20 cows and 50 sheep.

*Various dictionaries wrongly or unclearly address these issues.*

.............

[CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/stock) merely labels **stock** in the cattle etc sense 'plural'; as the plural form 'stocks' is available with other senses of the word, CED obviously means 'treated as plural' or better 'taking a plural verb-form'.

Comment: OED: **STOCK**:  A collective term for the implements (dead stock) and the animals (live stock: animals generally; animals of any kind kept or dealt in for use or profit) employed in the working of a farm, an industrial establishment, etc. See also rolling stock. 2. spec. = live stock ; the animals on a farm; also, a collective term for horses, cattle, and sheep bred for use or profit.

Comment: That certainly addresses the semantic part of your query; OED is usally the best place to check for sense 31 etc. It doesn't add a countness or a required verb-form flag for this sense though, apparently. Almost certainly non-count, and I'd say [almost?] always used with a singular verb; 'rolling stocks' sounds most unnatural.